# text selection not working in iframe inside vaadin application

Tags: java, internet-explorer, iframe, vaadin, vaadin7

In my vaadin application I use an ExternalResource to embed a JSP inside some of my vaadin views. The ExternalResource creates an iframe tag in the generated html code. 
The problem I am having now is that I cannot select any text inside that `iframe` when I am using Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge. Selection in Firefox and Google Chrome is working fine.

My code for adding the ExternalResource / iframe:

```
    BrowserFrame browser = new BrowserFrame();
    browser.setSource(new ExternalResource(myPageUrl));
    browser.setSizeFull();
    addComponent(browser);
```

Is there a fix to get the selection working in IE?

---

**Further information:**

- There are buttons in the JSP I am able to press regardless of the type of browser.
- When I use the DOM Explorers of the browsers I am able to see the html code of the JSP in any browser.

Comment: using the IE dev tool, select the Emulation tab, to see which IE emulation mode the TOP window is using (and how it was established) eg. Enterprise MOde, x-ua meta tag, User Compatibility list... etc. iframe documents inherit the emulation mode of the top document window.... it would appear that your top document is using IE10 or lower emulation...Use the Emulation tab of the dev tool to change the Emulation mode of the TOP document, to test if changing the emulation mode of the TOP document fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turned out that vaadin adds `-ms-user-select: none;`  to `.v-app` div's css. For some reason it blocks text selection in an iframe when using Internet Explorer.

Setting `-ms-user-select: text;` on iframe element seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, perfect! Thanks so much!